# Nock not intercepting request with superagent when passing response body

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, superagent, nock

I am using superagent for api calls and nock is not intercepting calls when I pass JSON on reply. If I dont pass anything but just response code it works fine.

----Unit test----

```
import nock from 'nock'

nock('http://somehost:80').log(console.log)
    .defaultReplyHeaders({'content-type': 'application/json'})
    .get('/location').query(true)
    .reply(404);
```

---- middleware-----

```
import request from 'superagent';
request.get('http://somehost:80/location')
         .query(action.searchParams)
         .end((err, res) => {
                console.log("response ", res)
                console.log("error ", err)
            });
```

When I run above test case it logs response and err. But when I change nock as :

```
nock('http://somehost:80').log(console.log)
            .defaultReplyHeaders({'content-type': 'application/json'})
           .get('/location').query(true)
           .reply(200,{hello:'hello!!!!'});
```

There is nothing logged in the console. Even if I just pass String as response it wont work.

But with or without response in the nock, the interceptor is returning true.
console.log node_modules\nock\lib\interceptor.js:318
matching http://somehost:80?sid=01&sid=02 to GET http://somehost:80/location with query(true): true

My best guess is its a problem with headers???

node -v : v4.3.1

"jest": "^21.2.1",
"nock": "^9.0.21",
"superagent": "3.5.2"

Comment: Did you ever find out?